# <jsp:setProperty name="po" property="*"/> is unable to set some form values

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cross-browser, javabeans

**when i submit the form it is taking all form values except some fields in firefox, but the same code is working fine in InternetExplorer.**

**index.jsp**

```
    <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
    <form name="frmEntry" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="mediator.jsp" onSubmit = "return confirmSubmit();">
    <table border="3" bordercolor="#000000" id="tableName2" width="80%"> 
        <%  
        if (po.getBldgId() != null) {
            for (int j=0; j < po.getBldgId().length; j++) { 
            %>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="bldgitemId">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="33%">
                                    <font color="#000000">  Building: </font>
                                    <div id="buildingInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                    <script language="JavaScript">
                                
                              createBuildingList(<%=j%>, buildingInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>);
                                    </script>

                            <td width="33%">
                                <font color="#000000">  Sub Account: </font>
                                <div id="subAccountInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                <script language="JavaScript">
createSubAccountList(<%=j%>, subAccountInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>, <%=po.getSubAccountId(j) %>);
                                
                            </script>
                             </td>
                             </tr>
                           </table>
```

In the above page(index.jsp) the two columns are filled by script. then we are submitting request to mediator.jsp, below is the medaitor.jsp where we are setting the all properties to bean. after that we forwarding to service class.

Note: in InternetExplorer the request payload contains all fields, but in firefox only above two fields are missing.

Note: in Firefox browser when i inspect i am able to see the fields name and everything same as IE.

Note: i removed all unnecessary code in both pages here

**mediator.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Mediator
</title>
</head>
<jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1>
Mediator JSP
</h1>

<jsp:setProperty name="po" property="*"/>
//some actions
```

**Edit1:**
**These are below two select tags are generated from script**.[image]

in the above pic you see highlighted name attributes, those values should be set to that bean, but they are not setting in firefox browser.

**please help, Thanks In Advance!...**

Comment: `...but in firefox only above two fields are missing.` - which two fields?

Comment: Those two columns in row, which are populated by script.

Comment: You should mention the names of the missing fields.

Comment: updated in the Question(Edit1)